# Is there a way to observe a file's 'availability status' via Windows command?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, onedrive

Our custom-built software has a problem with the way Microsoft OneDrive locks and syncs files that's in use. Due to this we have decided not to support cloud save files. The idea is that when a user points a load or save at a location that syncs to cloud a popup will notify them that it's not supported.

My problem is identifying the said location. While the easiest way would be to look for the folder name 'OneDrive', I feel like that is not foolproof since the folder's name can be changed.

I thought about checking if the file has an 'availability status' since that shows in explorer if the file is in the cloud, local, or sync-enabled.
Unfortunately I couldn't find any way to check that status other than visually, since I couldn't manually find references to the feature in the registry, command prompt or even the events log.

Example image:

[image]

Is there a command or method to find out this status of a file or folder like with the `attrib` command? As a final resort, perhaps Powershell can solve my problem?

**EDIT:** 
**Gerhard Barnard**'s solution worked for me. Here's a visual.

*(Thank you editors for turning these links into pictures while I rack up enough points for SO to trust me)* 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1NC2.jpg 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/myyWz.jpg

This is also available using `attrib`. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wv0ph.jpg

As mentioned by **aschipfl**, these features could possibly be absent on your system for reasons unknown as Microsoft's documentation seems outdated, however testing is underway.

**EDIT2:** 
I believe for these features to be available you should have OneDrive installed. It generally runs from C:\Users[username]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneDrive\OneDrive.exe. I'm contemplating simply looking for this file instead of inspecting folder contents before saving and prompting my users.

Comment: [Looks like this might be what you're after](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rodneyviana/2017/06/06/powershell-cmdlet-to-check-onedrive-for-business-or-onedrive-personal-status/)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thank you! That could work as a last resort, however since it's third-party it would be a pain to implement. I prefer using Windows built-in features first where possible.

Comment: It may not need to be "built-in", as OneDrive installs explorer extensions. The entire view you see there may be constructed using OneDrive extension features and not really possible to do using Windows **only** features and libraries.

Comment: As Lasse says, those entires are probably part of the OneDrive API, try looking for them there?

Comment: @phLOx I don;t have a system to check just this moment, but what happens when you check that attribute on a directory that is not part of onedrive?  Are the files just listed as "Available On This Device" or are they "Available OffLine"?  My system doesn't have one drive running but it does have the availability tag, and it shows all my files in any given directory as "Available offline"

Comment: @phLOX - I ask because I wonder if you ONLY need to avoid files which are "Available When Online" not files which are "Available Offline" or "Available on this Device" - the ones available only when online are pointers to the files on one drive, and may be the ony ones you need to avoid.  -- IE one drive could still sync the files just so long as the user keeps their file copy local.

Answer (score 1):

a File attribute is set to offline when it is offline.. So you can get the attributes for files without the offline attribute set:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /a-o') do echo %%i Available file.
```

the opposite obviously with displaying files that are offline:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /a:o') do echo %%i Offline file.
```

to see more about attributes, from `cmd.exe` run `dir /?` and see the `/A` switch help.

[image]

Comment: Well, there is no attribute specifier `O` for the `/A` option, at least on my computers (both Windows 7 and Windows 10)...

Comment: What Windows version are you using? I tried `dir /A:O` just to find out if it's missing in the documentation, but it says the parameter format is incorrect...

Comment: @aschipfl `Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.107]`

Comment: @aschipfl yeah seems it is a version thing going on here. Even [ss64](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) does not list it

Comment: Mine is older, namely version 10.0.14393.2906. Weird, the `/A:O` option is not even mentioned on [microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/dir)...

Comment: @aschipfl I suppose they started putting more cloud support in later versions. Anyway might as well then delete this answer then. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: Also working on `[Version 10.0.17763.737]`: `dir /a:o`, `dir /a:-o`, `dir /ao`, `dir /a-o`, although `dir /?` doesn't list that option.

Comment: `attrib` also suports the **O**ffline attribute and shows it with `attrib /?` (`[Version 10.0.17763.737]`)

Comment: @Stephan. Ok great. Thanks for that. Perhaps the MS documentation is just a little slow on getting released `:)`

Comment: @GerhardBarnard given that attributes are either assigned or not assigned, it's unclear how this one is used. Does oneDrive assign this attribute to all files it touches?  What if you copy them out of the directory?  Or are is files that are present locally given this attribute, and ones missing it are only available online?  Or it it that only files which are a place holder get the Offline attribute because they will not work when offline?

Comment: @BenPersonick. OneDrive files have the attribute set to "available when online" even if you are connected it will remain as that. Hence it is always seen as an offline file. Hope that males sense.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard I'm confused as to your meaning, in the OP's Question he put a screenshot that clearly shows two files which are synced on One Drive and have their availability status set to "Available On This Device", I don't have my laptop with one drive near me to check it myself, but it runs win 7 anyway so I could only check explorer integration.  Do you mean that any files One Drive touches will show as having the Offline Attribute Set regardless of whether the status is "Available On this Device" or "Available when online" ?

Comment: Thank you @GerhardBarnard your answer solves my problem 100%.

Comment: @phLOx ok that is great. Can you do from `cmd` type `ver` and show the output of your version please?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.737]